# Vuejs ajax call order: can I create new list item in vuex before ajax?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have a list of tasks in vuex. I have a button in a component that will add a task. I also have a backend server that will store the task in a DB.

Right now, I have it set up like this:

```
Button->Ajax->Backend Response->Update Vuex->Vue Updates Frontend
```

What I would like is:

```
Button->Update Vuex->Ajax/Vue each do their thing.
```

The issue I have is that I don't have an id for the item until the DB creates it. I could create a temporary id locally and send that to the server as a temporary id, but that seems messy. I wouldn't store it, I would just use it in vuex to update the object when it comes back from the server.

For example, let's say the database table tasks looks like this:

```
id | title
```

How would I know that the response from the server corresponds to the object I just pushed into Vuex? I can't do a find by title because it's not unique. I can't do a find by id == null because I might be creating more than one task before I get a response from the server.

I could do this in Vuex:

```
id | title | vuex_id
```

And I could use the response from the server to find the task with vuex_id that I set and update it with the id from the database.

Feels like there should be a cleaner way to make the the frontend react instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is the default (and for me the right one), go to the server and return (if it was successfully save) the id, add it to the task object and update the store.

Your second approach it's not appropriated (also for me), what if the save fails? you already have the task on the store and updated the UI, and then the task should be removed or implement some retry request method, to maintain the task in the UI. It will be harder to test and debug, and also harder to understand if you are note familiar with the code.

Comment: All of that is true, but many systems will allow for offline editing and resync once the system is reconnected to the network. I'm mostly asking how to update the client object with the DB id once the sync happens.

Answer (score 1):

`Button->Update Vuex->Ajax/Vue` is possible, hence the reason we have `Actions` to perform an async operation.

That said, you can always chain actions , if the first one returns a promise say it triggers a db save, waits for it to save successfully gets back the id and then trigger a subsequent action, if it fails you may want to handle it with retries and or whatever is appropriate, something along the lines of,

```
actions: {
 saveInDb ({ commit }) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // set time out below is your call to save into your Db
    setTimeout(() => {
    // save in db
      resolve(yourId)
    }, 1000)
  })
},
updateEverythingElse ({ dispatch, commit }) {
 return dispatch('SaveInDb').then((myNewId) => {
  commit('mutationToSaveId')
 }).catch((e) => {})
 }
}
```

I may not have captured everything you said completely, but just gave a brief idea how it *can possibly be done* from the little i have done.

**Based on the edited question**

This is the reason `guids` exist, and hence frontend/client sends in the Id, that said, looks like it might be an `identity` column for Id from your question, so there is then lesser options, of which you mentioned one with vuexid , the other would be **combinations of the column values like a composite key** could be as simple `${title}_${you_other_column}`, other than this you are probably left with option 1 of your doing.

**Food for thought**

Along those lines, my guess is, you are doing a batch update of `Array<Tasks>`, if am not mistaken, so i don't see the reason for your Vuex's mutations to be per row (per task object) and that it needs to be the entire collection , you may need to rethink that portion of it as i dont know the context and the reasoning behind updating one row at a time.

Comment: Thanks. When I hear back from the server, how would I identify the local task object in order to update it's DB id?

Comment: what do you mean by local task object? am not sure i understand

Comment: I'm not doing batch updates. Also, I get updates on tasks from other users on other systems, so I have to listen to full crud list. So I guess I can set a temp unique identifier and wait for the id to come back from the server.